# The tag is not fired because the item is loaded when I scroll

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track a vimeo play button but the video is loading on page when the user scroll to it.

What is the best way to get the event when this happen?
WindowsLoaded or DOM ready does not work.

Comment: is it loaded in an iframe?

Comment: yes it is, and the iframe is in "lazyloaded" mode

Comment: your problem is not with lazy loading. GTM has no issues tracking lazy loaded items. Your problem is with the iframe. You should check vimeo's documentation to see if they report events to the parent window. Otherwise you won't be able to track it.